# Is there a generic unbox function like in f#?

Tags: c#, f#, unboxing

I m trying to use object handlers and I have this working fine to put stuff in memory. But when I look up the object again I return:

```
object(object[,])
```

or

```
object(double[,])
```

how do I unbox this in c#?

```
object(double[,]) boxedobj = ....
double[,] unboxedobj = unbox(boxedobj);
```

Ideally I would like to do this in a generic way so that it doesnt matter whether the tybe is double[] or double[,] or object[,], etc

Comment: I don't get the point of your examples. Those are reference types, so boxing/unboxing has no effect.

Comment: I don't quite understand the example, but it sounds like a job for [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Why would you box stuff at the first place?

Comment: Sorry for wording this badly. I know its a reference type but I dont how to access the data. In my example the boxedobject contains a 2d matrix of mixed strings and numbers, i.e. object[,], but I cannot access boxedobject[2,2] because it is "boxed" within another object...

Comment: I box it because i put it in memory as key, object and I want to keep it generic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The F# `unbox` function is pretty much just doing cast to any other type that you specify. In C#, this could be written like this:

```
static R Unbox<R>(object anything) {
  return (R)anything;
}
```

So in your case with `double[,]` you'd need something like:

```
var array = (double[,])boxed;
```

In most cases `unbox<'R> anything` would just translate to casting using `(R)anything`. The only case where this does *not* work is when you are in another generic method and you are casting between two generic types. In that case, you need to go to `object` first (to make sure that the value is boxed):

```
static R Unbox<R, T>(T anything) {
    return (R)(object)anything;
}
```

Comment: c# `unbox<T>` isn't very useful, as type inference doesn't resolve on return value, so `T` has to be explicit.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm missing your point, casting to/from `object` should automatically box/unbox value types for you (an array is not a value type, BTW):

```
double d = 0.0;  // not boxed

object obj = d;  // boxed

double d2 = (double)obj;  // unboxed
```

The bigger question is - why do you *care* if its boxed or not?

Comment: Thank you! - see commment above for why or possibly because I m still learning and dont always know what the best way is...